# How can I use systemd-nspawn to PXE boot a container?

Tags: linux, systemd, ipxe, systemd-nspawn

I have configured my network environment to PXE boot VMs. I was wondering if it's possible to PXE boot a systemd-nspawn container

Comment: This doesn't make much sense. PXE provides information on how to boot a full system (or VM), but systemd-nspawn provides lightweight containers which share a kernel with the host.

Comment: Yeah I see what you mean and it's likely my understanding is a bit off, but it seems like it'd be possible to have a minimal container that starts up and then pulls down a filesystem and init binary to chain to the real container/OS. PXE as I understand it has a very similar role and so I thought it might be possible to use the same code